# To "write" matrix or lists() to a txt file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have problem to write the matrix output to my text file:

```
results_stress = []
Element_list = []        
tau_list = []
press_list = []
vms_list = []
spmax_list = [] 
spmin_list = [] 
results_stress = [Element_list, tau_list, press_list, vms_list, spmax_list, spmin_list]
print ('results_stress', results_stress)
```

Till here my code is working. Its printing a big lists on the screen. Now I want to write them to my text file.

```
wtrc ('%6.4f    %6.4f   %6.4f   %6.4f   %6.4f   %6.4f\n' %(Element_list, tau_list, press_list, vms_list, spmax_list, spmin_list))
```

Please help me to write all the above 6 lists in column format. So that I can easily import it to excel file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `wtrc`? What are the values of the lists? All floating numbers?

Comment: You can use a loop to build the string.

Comment: Has every list the same length? Please provide an example of input and output.

Comment: Yes, every lists has same length. I need 6 columns so that I can do calculations on the table.

Comment: Use a for loop like: `for i in range(len(tau_list)): s += '%6.4f %6.4f\n' % (Elements_list[i], tau_list[i])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the string in a for-loop:

```
s = ''
for i in range(len(tau_list)):
    s += '%6.4f    %6.4f   %6.4f   %6.4f   %6.4f   %6.4f\n' %(Element_list[i], tau_list[i], press_list[i], vms_list[i], spmax_list[i], spmin_list[i])
wtrc(s)
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas. It worked. 
Could you please tell me about "wtrc"?

Comment: `wtrc` is custom function someone else programmed. It is no standard function. You are importing it from a local file or you are defining it in your script. I can't say anything about it except it takes a string as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

An example for you:

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: num_fmt = '6.4f'

In [2]: results_stress = [[1.2, 10.2], [2.3, 20.3], [3.4, 30.4], [4.5, 40.5], [5.6, 50.6], [6.7, 60.7]]

In [3]: ss = []

In [4]: for nums in zip(*results_stress):
   ...:     ss.append((' '*4).join(f'{n:{num_fmt}}' for n in nums))
   ...:

In [5]: s = '\n'.join(ss)

In [6]: print(s)
1.2000    2.3000    3.4000    4.5000    5.6000    6.7000
10.2000    20.3000    30.4000    40.5000    50.6000    60.7000
```